# Why is there the KeyError 'main' in my code?

Tags: python

I have tried a lot to resolve the problem but everytime I'm getting the same problem...i.e. key error in the city_weather at main

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import City
from .forms import CityForm

# Create your views here.

def weather(request):

    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=imperial&appid=f5f13c3f6d997b396795738b674115cc'
    city = 'Delhi'


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        form.save()

    form = CityForm()

    cities = City.objects.all()

    weather_data = []

    for city in cities:

        r = requests.get(url.format(city)).json()
        #print(r.text)
        city_weather = {
            'city': city.name,
            'temperature': r['main']['temp'],
            'description': r['weather'][0]['description'],
            'icon':  r['weather'][0]['icon']
        }

        weather_data.append(city_weather)

    print(weather_data)

    #print(city_weather)
    context = {'weather_data': weather_data, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'weather.html', context)
```

I expected no errors but I'm getting the
'temperature': r['main']['temp'],
KeyError: 'main'

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the admin page and delete the cities you created before, because you are getting an error because you defined undefined city names.

Comment: This is likely the cause, which means this question was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
city_weather = {
            'city': city.name,
            'temperature': r['main']['temp'],
            'description': r['weather'][0]['description'],
            'icon':  r['weather'][0]['icon']
               } #you need to close the dictionary here

    weather_data.append(city_weather)
```

Comment: url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=imperial&appid=f5f13c3f6d997b396795738b674115cc' then here is the problem

Comment: or you can try chnaging this 'city': city.name, to  'city' : r['name'],

Comment: I replaced 'city': city.name, to 'city' : r['name']..... Again got the key error with 'city' : r['name']

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a KeyError , the semantic meaning is that the key being looked for could not be found. 
Just include the closing curly bracket ('}') for the dictionary "**city_weather**"

Comment: This is a SyntaxError (caused by someone's edit), not a KeyError.